# Which is correct — as much as ... or as many as ... used with a percentage?

Tags: idioms

I’m unsure which is correct to use in the following sentence — “as much as” or “as many as”? Here’s the sentence:

> As ___ as 88% of all real estate transactions come from repeat and referral business.

I originally assumed that "much" refers to "88%," but when I read the sentence with "many," it sounds fine, too.

Comment: Another sentence I have come across has the same issue: 

>As many much as 74% of clients are willing to give their former realtors referrals …

That sounds fine, too. Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

The correct quantifier depends on the count/mass status of the noun modified by the percentage, rather than the number in the percentage.  Although '%' originally meant 'per hundred', it is often used to indicate a fraction that can be applied to uncountable things (like 'water').  In your example, 'transactions' is a count noun, so 'many' is appropriate.